# Is it safe to make a List public for using it as a DataGridView's datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

i am creating a C# class library that reads data from a socket and store some data in a list. This list will change more the once per second during execution time.

In need this list to be the content of a `dataGridView` of a winforms application, but i'm wondering how  can i expose it out of my library.

Is it safe to declare the List as public in the classLibrary like:

```
public class THRManager
{
    public List <GaugeItem> outSource;
    ...
```

and then on the WinForm side:

```
public TMRMainForm()
{
    THRManager thrC = new THRManager();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = thrC.outSource;
    ...
```

Is this safe? If not, what's the best way?

Thx!

==================EDIT

Should i use DataTable or BindingSource ?

Comment: Wheres a BindingSource involved?

Comment: I edited to be a List, but basically the question doesn't vary(probably much more senseful)

Comment: Sounds like the only one allowed to change the list should be THRManager so it would be better to publish the list as a ReadOnlyList via a Property.

Comment: A DataTable is unnecessary. If outSource is goint to be bound to more than one Control putting a BindingSource in between might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ReadOnlyCollection` but create it once in your constructor or where ever else you need them, in order not to do `new ReadOnlyCollection...` every time you access it.

```
public class THRManager
{
   private List<GaugeItem> outsource;
   private ReadOnlyCollection<GaugeItem> outSourceReadOnly;

    public THRManager()
    {
        outSource = new List<GaugeItem>();
        outSourceReadOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<GaugeItem>(outSource);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<GaugeItem> OutSource 
    { 
        get { return outSourceReadOnly; } 
    }
}
```

Hope code works without syntax errors :)

Comment: Will i need to rebind the dataGrid every time a change occurs?

Comment: @Pizzaboy Sorry... very late answer... no you don't have to bind it again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a safer option when publishing an inner collection.

```
private List<GaugeItem> outSource;

public ReadOnlyCollection<GaugeItem> OutSource 
{ 
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<GaugeItem>(outSource); } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question again because i started the question usin a dictionary